# How to make a diamond shape with the user input being the width of the middle line?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I'm working on a functions and parameters exercise:

> Write a function that will print out a "diamond" of any size and with any symbol specified by the user. The size is the width of the diamond. Test it.

I've tried searching on the web for answers to my question, but all of them have the user input being the number of rows and that's not what I'm looking for. The code I have so far is satisfactory. Any help?

```
userSize = int(input("Enter size: "))
userSymbol = input("Enter symbol: ")

def drawCross(symbol, size):
    num = 0
    for i in range(1, size + 1):
        for j in range(1, (size - i) + 1):
            print(end=" ")

drawCross(userSymbol, userSize)
```

Comment: It would help if you actually printed the symbol somewhere...

Comment: Think about how the width of the diamond and the number of rows are related.